# MDI Form issues with datasource for child forms

Tags: vb.net, forms, datasource, bindingsource

I have an MDI application where the MDI form is required to store a bindingsource and dataset. The child forms are "detail forms" in that they should allow the user to alter the properties of each object instance in the parent MDI form dataset.

I have tried to go about it as follows:

Pass the bindingsource object from the MDI parent into the constructor for the new child form. However I get the following error

```
"An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot bind to the property or column Z1 on the DataSource."
```

Z1 is a public property of my "Pipe" Class which is one object I have created a datasource from in visual studio wizard.

My code for the MDI form 'Main'

```
'This is the open child form button click handler
Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripMenuItem2.Click
    Dim p As New PipeForm(Me.PipeBindingSource)
    Me.Show(p)
End Sub

    'This is the overloaded show helper method for the MDI form
    Private Overloads Sub Show(f As Form)
    For Each testForm As Form In Application.OpenForms
        If testForm.GetType().Equals(f.GetType()) Then
            f.Activate()
            Return
        End If
    Next
    f.MdiParent = Me
    f.Show()
End Sub
```

And my code for the Child form 'PipeForm'

```
'constructor
Public Sub New(bs As BindingSource)


    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    Me.PipeBindingSource = bs

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

End Sub
```

I can have separate PipeBindingSource objects on each form and work with them  through textbox inputs with no issues. The problem arises when i try to set the PipeBindingSource from the parent to the child as equal.

Comment: look at the ctor posted for PipeForm.  It explains why you get the exception: `InitializeComponent()` is **required** by the designer and `Add any initialization __AFTER__ the InitializeComponent() call.`.  a) you added code before the call, b) the overload doesnt have such a call at all.  Without that call, none of the controls and components are instanced yet.  Drill into that procedure to see what it does.

Comment: Thanks Plutonix, Im still a newbie so appreciate people like yourself pointing out the obvious mistake

Comment: I changed the declaration to after the initiliazle call and still getting error. I can see that what you mean initialize component() creates an instance. However if assign the bindingsource of the MDI form to the child form I do not understand why both are not linked together

Comment: you should edit your post to show the current code (there were 2 things to change).

Comment: I got it going by deleting all the VS designer generated code and doing the databinding manually. I still dont completely understand why it doesnt work as per the code above (using the designer generated datasource and bindings). I think it is something to do with instances , will investigate tomorrow nite. The show override takes the form as the input which has the bindingsource of the main MDI form passed into the constructor for the PipeForm , i dont understand why this would need to be changed as per your b) above. Thanks